# How to force reboot based on return code of an external application?

Tags: inno-setup

Can I somehow force reboot if an external application returns exit code 5 ?

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\e.exe; Parameters: Z; Description: {cm:ALaunchProgram,{#ti}};
```

If its not possible with RUN section, where can I make a call to ShellExec so that executable is run during post phase.

Comment: I believe that if external installer gives signal, that restart is needed, Inno Setup displays such message on the `FinishPage`. You can also check: `[Setup]: RestartIfNeededByRun=yes`
However default value is `yes`...
Description:
When set to yes, and a program executed in the [Run] section queues files to be replaced on the next reboot (by calling MoveFileEx or by modifying wininit.ini), Setup will detect this and prompt the user to restart the computer at the end of installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to trigger a reboot from a `[Run]` entry unless the executed file does something that Inno can autodetect as requiring a reboot (such as scheduling a file to be replaced or deleted on reboot).  This is controlled via the `RestartIfNeededByRun` setting, which defaults to `yes`.

If you want to be able to capture the return value and do something interesting with it, you must use `[Code]`.  If you must do it post-install, then the suggested place is `CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)` (which actually occurs after the `[Run]` entries normally do).

At this point you can use `Exec` to run your program and check the exit code, optionally setting some global variable indicating whether it wanted to reboot.  You can then use that value in your `NeedRestart` event function.

However before going down this path, if the thing you are trying to run is actually some sort of prerequisite component you should strongly consider installing it from `PrepareToInstall` instead.  An example of this is included with Inno, including an example of triggering a reboot between the prerequisite install and the main application install.